# Spring Boot YAML Config w/ unique file name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read in a simple yml file for a Spring Boot application located at resources/wtf.yml. The following application works if the default application.yml filename is used, but not if I change the filename. Anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = {"wtf.yml"}) //classpath:wtf.yml
public class SomeApp {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SomeApp.class, args);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println(readTimeout);
  }

  @Value("${readTimeout}")
  public int readTimeout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spring.config.name` or `spring.config.location` properties as described in [Spring Boot guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: It'd be nice to be able to set a property file location without providing a command line property or as an argument in another yaml file.